# 'Next badge' overflows if it and the newest badge have long names

Tags: bug, status-review, design, profile-page, badge-progress

The name of 'next badge' overflows its progress bar if both the 'newest badge' and itself have long names:

[image]

[Here](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/users/60957/ishaan-manish?tab=topactivity) is a live example [provided by @NilayGhosh](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/381886/295232), and a [Wayback Machine snapshot](https://web.archive.org/web/20220908112347/https://aviation.stackexchange.com/users/60957/ishaan-manish?tab=topactivity) in case it ever changes.

Comment: For me a long badge title, with a space in it, just wraps. https://i.stack.imgur.com/QGZSC.png So this is just a case of a bad flex box.

Comment: The possible solution is to use one row for "newest" and another for "next". Just found the [similar situation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BPRqN.jpg). Too long "status-review" I think.